# Dot Net Entity Framework database update doesn't create tables in mysql database

Tags: c#, mysql, database, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm using `MySql` as database with the official connection provider. I'm trying it with the next project example (asp.net core 1.0) on a mac:

```
public class BloggingContext : DbContext
{
    public BloggingContext(DbContextOptions<BloggingContext> options)
        : base(options)
    { }

    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}
```

And in my Startup.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var connection = @"server=localhost;userid=efcore;port=3306;database=blogsFinal;sslmode=none;";
        services.AddDbContext<BloggingContext>(options => options.UseMySQL(connection));

        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc();
    }
```

In my project.json I also add

```
"dependencies": {
   ...
     "MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore": "7.0.5-ir21",

    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    }
}
```

and

```
  "tools": {
    ...,
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },
```

When I run `dotnet ef migrations add v1`, works fine and creates the migration files, but when I execute `dotnet ef database update` the database is created but tables not and throws this output

```
System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
   at MySQL.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MySQLHistoryRepository.get_ExistsSql()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.GetAppliedMigrations()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Cli.DatabaseUpdateCommand.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args)
The method or operation is not implemented.
```

Comment: Could you please post the code which is executing for said Update, which is throwing error?

Comment: This is the code [link](https://github.com/careuno/newtestEfcoreMysql) the error is when I execute dotnet ef database update

Answer (score 8):

Exceptions says it. The official MySQL Provider from Oracle doesn't support it migrations or scaffolding yet.

It will only create the Database on first execution of `context.Database.EnsureCreated()`. Any changes done after that, won't be applied. You have to drop the whole DB and create a new one, losing all data.

Say thanks to Oracle ;)

**Update**

With the release of 7.0.6-IR31 [package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore/7.0.6-IR31) migrations do work, but scaffolding still doesn't.

Comment: Thank you, With SapientGuardian.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql works fine

Comment: A link to the documentation would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

As Tseng said, this is a known issue. Here is the bug report from 14 Sept 2016.

> Missing implementation for running EntityFramework Core code first migration

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=82981