# EF Core `update-database` on MySql fails with `__EFMigrationsHistory' doesn't exist`

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I Create new project in .net core 1.1 with individual user account identity. I Add MySql Provider in Startup.cs:

```cs
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => 
        options.UseMySQL(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

But when i try do `update-database` i get error like this:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Table 'cloud.__EFMigrationsHistory' doesn't exist    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int64& insertedId)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.MySQLRelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, String executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues, Boolean closeConnection)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.GetAppliedMigrations() 
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String contextType) 
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Cli.DatabaseUpdateCommand.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0()
    at Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args)
 Table 'cloud.__EFMigrationsHistory' doesn't exist
```

What I should do?

Comment: This has nothing to do with ASP.NET Core or MySQL. That's an Entity Framework error that appears in *all* versions when you try to *update* instead of create the database. The message explains why - the migrations history table used by EF to check which migrations have already been applied is missing

Comment: But why i get this error? This is new project with standard asp.net core identity added in template.

Comment: Because the *provider* may be have a bug and not create the table. Happened eg [2 years ago with the Postgres provider](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/884)

Comment: Do this is no way to use MySql with asp.net identity in .net core 1.1?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This isn't related to ASP.NET Identity or ASP.NET Core. This is related to Entity Framework in general. When you update a database, EF uses the `__EFMigrationsHistory` to record which migrations were executed so it doesn't perform them again in the future.

This functionality is implemented by the *database provider*, not EF itself. There was at least one case where the Npgsql provider for PostgresSQL [didn't create the table](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/852).

The solution is easy - create the table yourself :

```
CREATE TABLE `__EFMigrationsHistory` 
( 
    `MigrationId` nvarchar(150) NOT NULL, 
    `ProductVersion` nvarchar(32) NOT NULL, 
     PRIMARY KEY (`MigrationId`) 
);
```

**UPDATE**

There was *another* [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40597534/ef-core-table-efmigrationshistory-doesnt-exist) in 2016. This is a bug of the official MySQL provider.  The fix is to create the table. Not the only one either. Asynchronous operations are faked by running them on a different thread for example.

I'd suggest you investigate third-party MySQL providers like [Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql). They [found and fixed](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/issues/99) the migration history bug 1 year ago.

Given that the owner of MySQL is *Oracle*, don't expect a lot of progress on the connector. Or the database.

Comment: I use Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql and its start work.
Thanks!

Comment: Wow, 2020 ... this "official" provider is a complete joke. Just run right into this bug using the Oracle provider. Now I'd love to see someone try to convince me that isn't political.

Comment: @Jammer let me put it this way ... does Oracle get any license money out of MySQL? That's why critical features like real backups are in the $5K/year Enterprise version, and why the analytic and window functions like ROW_NUMBER() in MySQL 8 took 8 years.to come out. You got spoiled by Sql Server Express

Comment: I've never heard working code referred to as being "spoiled".