# Erratic error when calling Database.MigrateAsync in EF Core 3.0 against a SQLite database

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core

I'm developing a Xamarin.Forms app which uses a SQLite database accessed via Entity Framework Core (version 3, I'm currently using a prerelease version because I missed the release of the official 3.0, I will upgrade soon).

Every time the app starts, soon after the ApplicationContext class is instantiated, I call Database.MigrateAsync to be sure that the database is upgraded to the latest version of the model. I know I could greatly improve performances by not calling MigrateAsync every time the app starts but only after the first run of a new version, but it's not the point here.

The problem is, in a very small percentage of my users (roughly 0.5%) MigrateAsync throws an exception of type `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException: SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: __EFMigrationsHistory'` (reported via VS App Center Crash Report functionality).
Now, I know that __EFMigrationHistory is the table used by EF Core to keep track of applied migrations, and the first time the database file is created should be created by the framework itself.

So, how an error like this is even possible? Because, if the table does not exist, it should be created, while if it exists, it should be used to consider which migrations have already been applied. Maybe EF Core tries to create the table, fails for some unknown reasons, then tries to read it throwing this exception? But what can cause it to fail create the table? And what can I do in this case?

I'm currently not able to say if this exception is thrown at the first run of the app (when no migration should ever have been applied) or subsequently, because I currently do not track this kind of information. Also, I never experienced such exception during development.
What I can say, the exception is captured in a catch block, reported to App Center, and then rethrown, which by the way should cause a crash, which in turn seems not to happen, according to App Center reports. This can be related to the fact that the exception is thrown in asynchronous code that maybe is not awaited or is handled by the caller (the initialization code is called by Autofac after instantiating my ApplicationContext class), but that's not essential to my question.

This is the code where I call MigrateAsync:

```
    public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
    {

        // Other code...

        public async Task<ApplicationContext> Initialize()
        {
            if (IsInitialized) return this;
            IsInitialized = true;

            try
            {
                await Database.MigrateAsync();
                Analytics.TrackEvent("Migration OK");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Crashes.TrackError(ex, new Dictionary<string, string> { { Globals.CrashProperty.Context.ToString(), "Migration" } });
                throw;
            }
            return this;
        }
    }
```

Here is the code where I register with Autofac for when the single instance of ApplicationContext is created:

```
public class AppModule : Autofac.Module
    {
        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            // Other services registrations…

            builder.Register(ctx => new ApplicationContext(ctx.Resolve<IFileService>(
                new TypedParameter(typeof(string), Globals.DbFileName),
                new TypedParameter(typeof(FilePathType), FilePathType.AppFolder)).FilePath, ctx.Resolve<IResourceContainer>())).SingleInstance();

            base.Load(builder);
        }

        protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(IComponentRegistry componentRegistry, IComponentRegistration registration)
        {
            registration.Activated += async (_, args) =>
            {
                if (args.Instance is ApplicationContext context && !context.IsInitialized)
                {
                    await context.Initialize();
                }
            };
            base.AttachToComponentRegistration(componentRegistry, registration);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the stack trace of the exception as reported by VS App Center:

```
Microsoft.Data.Sqlite
SqliteException.ThrowExceptionForRC (System.Int32 rc, SQLitePCL.sqlite3 db)
Microsoft.Data.Sqlite
SqliteCommand+<PrepareAndEnumerateStatements>d__62.MoveNext ()
Microsoft.Data.Sqlite
SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader (System.Data.CommandBehavior behavior)
Microsoft.Data.Sqlite
SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader ()
Microsoft.Data.Sqlite
SqliteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery ()
System.Data.Common
DbCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal
RelationalCommand.ExecuteAsync (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.IRelationalConnection connection, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.DbCommandMethod executeMethod, System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] parameterValues, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations
MigrationCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.IRelationalConnection connection, System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] parameterValues, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal
MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQueryAsync (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] migrationCommands, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.IRelationalConnection connection, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal
Migrator.MigrateAsync (System.String targetMigration, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old question, but I had the same issue and thought it worth updating this as this was the first result I found via google.

This error occurs when you use the following to create the database:

```
context.Database.EnsureCreated();
```

If this is used to create the database initially, the __EFMigrationsHistory table is never created and will prevent migrations from working.

If you have a full migration history, the below may not work for you. EF will try and apply all migrations, including those with tables that may already exist. Without manually populating the __EFMigrationsHistory table with the correct migrations to match the state - you may have to refer to the final answer below.

Following an answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40597534/ef-core-table-efmigrationshistory-doesnt-exist/40615387), you can do the following to correct this issue:

Once the __EFMigrationsHistory table has been created, the rest of the update should run.

```
CREATE TABLE `__EFMigrationsHistory` ( `MigrationId` nvarchar(150) NOT NULL, `ProductVersion` nvarchar(32) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`MigrationId`) );
```

Alternatively, generate the script of your migration(s) and apply to the database manually using this command in Package Manager Console:

```
Script-Migration
```

If you need to generate All scripts, you can use this command:

```
Script-Migration -from 0
```

In addition to this answer, and if you already have several migrations that won't apply because tables and columns already exist, you can do the following:

**(Warning, this will drop the existing database, and all of its data - this is a last option - not a first)**

```
if (!context.Database.GetAppliedMigrations().Any())
    context.Database.EnsureDeleted()
```

Then follow this up with:

```
content.Database.Migrate()
```

This will ensure that if no migrations are present, the database is deleted and reinitialised with the migration table, and all pending migrations are applied.

Comment: OP's question may have been a concurrency issue. If you want to migrate on startup, you need to ensure nothing else can run before the migration has finished.

Comment: Thank you @Joel for your answer. I knew about the conflict between EnsureCreated and Migrate, and in fact I didn't use EnsureCreated. The problem with my app was much simpler, and had to do with the fact that I registered the app to open many kinds of files (not only sqlite ones). So some users tried to use my app to open files that were not database at all, and this caused the error. In fact, sometimes the more reasonable error "File is not a database" was reported, but other times the error about migrations that confused me.